# How do I install 'convert' on a linux system?

Tags: linux, redhat, image, convert

My application needs to call 'convert' - http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm

But its not present on my redhat system. How / what do I install?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

convert is part of the package ImageMagick; try `sudo yum install ImageMagick` (or other privilege escalation method as appropriate to your system).

Answer (score 23):

To install **convert** try package manager. Convert is part of ImageMagick package, convert is one of utilities.

Under Debian is possible use

> sudo dpkg --install imagemagick

or

> sudo apt-get install imagemagick

It is about 419 MB of space.

Comment: The question was about a redhat system and not debian.

Comment: I'm sorry for spam and missunderstand. To **install convert** under redhat is better use yum or rpm, I guess.

Answer (score 19):

Next time you need a command like this you can figure out what package to install by running something like `yum whatprovides '*/convert'`.

Comment: Heh, beat me to it!

Comment: does apt-get have something like this? (`whatprovides`)

Answer (score -1):

For the installation in Fedora 27 from the terminal:

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick -y
```